# Is there a way to take a specific subset of neurons as the output in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

Let's say the second to last layer of my neural network outputs a tensor with shape [7].

How would I make my output layer be only a subset of the previous `7` outputs, for example an array of the values at index `0, 3, and 6`?

For example, if my second to last output is `[0.2, 1, 6, 1, 2, 0.87, 1.7]`, how could I get the last layer to output `[0.2, 1, 1.7]`?

Comment: Use `tf.gather_nd(x,[[0],[3],[6]])`

Comment: Thanks tf.gather works well.